# create hyperlink with hyperlink+inputbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a user profile page which url's first part is static and last part is dynamic like this

```
    <a href="mywebsite.com/view/[ID]"> View profile </a>
```

I want to create an inputbox where i can type id in input box and given id auto complete hyperlink with input-box value like this.

```
Type user ID [input-box]
<a href="mywebsite.com/view/[input-box value]"> View profile </a>
```

please tell me how can i do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can replace the URL with JavaScript using the location.replace function. You can tie that to a button's onclick event.

```
Type user ID: <input type='text' id='userid'>
<button type='button' onclick="location.replace('http://mywebsite.com/view/'+document.getElementById('userid').value);">View Profile</button>
```

You will likely want to add some error handling code. What if the User ID field is blank? What if they type "Mushroom" and you expect a number? What if they type ../../../index.html? If it is just for you, then you can assume you will type something valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `jQuery` for that, i.e:

```js
$( "#in" ).keyup(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$( "#out" ).text( '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/view/'+value+'"> View profile </a>' );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="in">
<p id="out"></p>
```

---

PS: [How is JavaScript different from Java?](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml)

Answer (score -1):

Your code can be like this,

```
    user ID: <input type="text" id="user_id" value="" onkeypup="javascript:change_url(this.value);”>

<a href="mywebsite.com/view/” id=“view_profile"> View profile </a>
```

The above code calls a javascript function, change_url() on each key up.

You can write the function either in the header between [head] tags or at bottom before [/body] tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function change_url(input_user_id) {

        //-- get the value of old href
        var x = document.getElementById("view_profile").href;

        //-- append input-field user id
        x = x + "" + input_user_id;

        //-- set href value back with appened user_id
        document.getElementById("view_profile").href = x;
    }

</script>
```